# Using Where and Count on two tables

Tags: mysql, count, where-clause

I have two tables

```
Foods
----------
ID    Name
----------
1. Chips
2. Pizza
3. Fish
4. Pasta

People
-----------------
ID Name    FoodID
-----------------
1. Robert       3
2. Norman       2
3. Leonard      4
4. Huey         3
```

What I'm supposed to do is retrieve any food that belongs to more than one person. Now I'm supposed to do this by means of COUNT and WHERE. Possibly might need to do an INNER JOIN.

It should be simple but I'm just not seeing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to join the tables on the common field.  The WHERE is serving as an inner join.  Then GROUP BY Foods.name aggregate rows by food type.  Count is an aggregate operator that always works with the GROUP BY.

```
SELECT Foods.Name, Count(*)
FROM Foods, People
WHERE Foods.ID = People.Food
GROUP BY Foods.Name
HAVING COUNT(*)>1;
```

Omit the first count(*) if you just want the list of foods.

Answer (score 1):

```
select f.name, p.name, count(f.id) as total from foods f, people p 
where (f.id = p.FoodID)
group by f.name
having total > 1
order by f.name
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b2a63/10

Answer (score -1):

```
select * from food inner join people  on people.id = food.id group by people.name
```

Comment: i think you need a count in there to actually answer the question